# Running synchronous queries in Parse Framework Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've written an asynchronous cloud background job for the Parse Framework that generates a display username for each user based off of their email before the '@' symbol. Unfortunately I'm getting an error "too many count operations" when I run the job. Is there a way to have the queries and saves run in series as opposed to in parallel? I saw in the documentation it is possible with promises, but I'm confused as to how to make it work with nested queries.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("generateUsernameForEveryUser", function(request, status) {

  // Set up to modify user data
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var counter = 0;
  // Query for all users
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.each(function(user) {

    createUsernameForUser(user, 0, {
      success: function(username) {
        if(username == null) {
          status.error();
        } else {
          user.set("displayUsername", username);
          user.set("displayUsernameUppercase", username.toUpperCase());
          user.save();
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        status.error("Error: " + error.message);
      }         

    });

  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Username generation completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
  });

});

function createUsernameForUser(user, count, callback) {  

  var generatedUsername = user.getEmail().substring(0, user.getEmail().indexOf("@"));

  if(count > 0) {
    //Quotes added to ensure no math is done between generatedUsername and count
    generatedUsername = "" +  generatedUsername + "" + count;
  }

  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  userQuery.equalTo("displayUsernameUppercase", generatedUsername.toUpperCase());
  userQuery.count({

    success: function(userCount) {

      if(userCount > 0) {
        createUsernameForUser(user, count + 1, {
          success : function(responseUsername) {
            callback.success(responseUsername);
          }, 
          error: function(error) {
            callback.error(error.message);
          }
        });
      }

      else {
        callback.success(generatedUsername);
      }

    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Error trying to count users: " + error.message);
      callback.error("Error trying to count users: " + error.message);
    }

   });//End of userQuery call

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer but will be helpful for people going through this.

`too many count operations` error returned because query.each will work only if we have a data of 100 or lesser rows for that class.

We can acheive the same requirement as follows:

1. Get all the users.
2. Create the usernames and store them into an array. For more refer to parse.com batch operations.
   `var users = new Array();
   .... push all the created user objects to users ....
   Parse.Object.saveAll(users);  //save the list -`

Hope this solves.